# Splitting a column into rows on ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Hello I am getting rows like below.

```
ID, NAME,EMAIL,PHONENUMBER
123,ABC, qwe@poi.com|asd@lkj.com, 3636|7363
234,DEF,sjs@djd.com|sndir@fmei.com|cmrjje@fmcj.com,5845|4958|5959
```

The each person can have multiple emails and phone numbers, separated by |. First email and first phone are linked. Second email and second phone are linked. So they need to be in same records. Can I split this record to multiple rows with one email and one phone per record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use data flow to achieve that. I created a test, the overall architecture and debug result is as follows:
[image]

1. My source dataset is a text file in Azure data lake gen2.`Source1` and `Source2` use this same data source.
   [image]
2. At `DerivedColumn1` activity, we can select the **EMAIL** column and enter expression `split(EMAIL,'|')` to split this column to an Array.
   [image]
3. At `Flatten1` activity, select `EMAIL[]` as **Unroll by** and **Unroll root**.
   [image]
4. At `SurrogateKey1` activity, enter `ROW_NO` and start value 1.
   [image]
   The data preview is as follows:
   [image]
5. `Source2` is the same as `Source1`, so we jump to `DerivedColumn2` activity, we can select the PHONENUMBER column and enter expression split(PHONENUMBER,'|') to split this column to an Array.
   [image]
6. At `Flatten2` activity, select PHONENUMBER[] as Unroll by and Unroll root.
   [image]
7. At `SurrogateKey2` activity, enter `ROW_NO` and start value 1. The data preview is as follows:
   [image]
8. At `Join1` activity, we can Inner join these two data flows with the key column `ROW_NO`.
   [image]
   The data preview is as follows:
   [image]
9. At `Select1` activity, we can select the columns what we need.
   [image]
   The data preview is as follows:
   [image]
10. Then we can sink the result to our destination.

That's all.